# Is there a difference between having class methods vs top-level functions in terms of Javascript parsing speed?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, garbage-collection, v8

I'm developing a single page application and I have many files that are formatted like this:

```
export function a() {
  // .. code here
}

export function b() {
  // .. code here
}

export function c() {
  // .. code here
}
```

As a result, when the user first loads the app, all of these functions need to read and parsed and presumably loaded into memory by the Javascript engine (v8 in this case). You can tell this is occurring because if you put a `console.log` in that file, it will be triggered when the application initially loads.

This is leading to somewhat high initial loading times because I have close to 1000 top level functions like this.

Would there be any difference in terms of loading speed if the functions were instead inside of a class, like this?

```
export class Misc {
  a() {}
  b() {}
  c() {}
}
```

The logic being, the underlying Javascript engine may potentially may be lazy and defer loading of the inner functions until the first instance of the object was created. Also, it may be easier to tell when the functions are no longer in scope (no Misc objects exist), and thus those functions could be garbage collected and released from memory (instead of just always having 1000 functions loaded at all times).

Is there any merit to this intuition? Or is there truly no difference?

Comment: The loading speed is mostly limited by having to import every files seperately, the parsing is almost negligible, and parsing a class _should_ be slower since javascript classes are just syntactic sugar that gets converted to Objects and Function calls in the background, so since it's sugar it should be slower as it needs to do more work. So it would probably be faster, but only because you bundle more functions toether in one file. If not, the difference will be very small. You might just want to bundle all those functions into one file with minimal changes.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the insight!

Comment: Just because there are 1,000 functions, that doesn't mean there will be substantial startup cost. Are you seeing a performance issue of some kind, or prematurely optimizing? Separately: If you don't need those functions to start with, when *do* you need them?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am developing a single page application with Vite, and generally I only need a couple functions per route, but I have many different routes. There's currently a decent startup time, but it's not _that_ bad I suppose. Just making sure this architecture will scale I suppose before I get too deep with it

Comment: I'd worry about scaling issues when you run into scaling issues. :-) (At which point, you might consider file-per-route or group of routes, code splitting, and dynamically loading the route handler. Or something. But if you do it when you have a problem, then you'll know if the solution solves the problem. Until then, I'd say keep it simple.)

Comment: Okay sounds good thanks for the advice!

Comment: If you have an easy way to generate both versions of the code in question you can put each version on something like https://jsperf.app and run the comparison in your browser(s) to see the performance numbers and get a real measurable answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and parsed and presumably loaded into memory by the Javascript engine (v8 in this case). You can tell this is occurring because if you put a console.log in that file, it will be triggered when the application initially loads.

If you put a `console.log` into a function, will it log? If no, how do you know it was "parsed"? The parser could also skip functions and search for the end of the function (okay, it needs some logic to find the end) and parse the function fully later when it is actually executed. So yes, it will spend some time scanning through all your code to find the names of all the functions and global variables, but it won't necessarily create a full blown AST.

You might be interested in reading https://v8.dev/blog/preparser.

> Would there be any difference in terms of loading speed if the functions were instead inside of a class, like this?

I doubt that this is something you can measure (in non artificial benchmarks).

> The logic being, the underlying Javascript engine may potentially may be lazy and defer loading of the inner functions until the first instance of the object was created.

Right, but It'll also do this for "outer functions".

> instead of just always having 1000 functions loaded at all times

As outlined in [Does Javascript ever garbage collect functions or constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145198/does-javascript-ever-garbage-collect-functions-or-constants/77160263#77160263), your definition of "functions loaded" is overly generic, there is "the function source code", "the function object" and various "runtime representations". So "having 1000 functions loaded" could just mean 1000 * n bytes (with n being a relatively low number).

---

Instead of worrying if loading "code X" or "code Y" is better, I guess you should rather worry if loading that code is needed at all, and if it might be better to split up the code and only load the parts that are absolutely necessary at first, and then load further code once it is needed. With bundlers like Webpack, if you split up your code into multiple (semantic) components and lazily import larger components, the bundler will automatically come up with a rather good strategy to split your code into multiple bundles.